# R: Revalue multiple special characters in a data.frame

Tags: r, data-cleaning

R noob here..

I have the following data frame

```
>data  
 Value Multiplier
1  15    H
2   0    h
3   2    +
4   2    ?
5   2    k
```

where the multiplier is of class `factor`. The values of `K` & `k` is `3`, `+` is `5` and `?` is `2`.

I have used

```
> data$Multiplier <-  revalue(data$Multiplier, c("+"="5"))
> data$Multiplier <-  revalue(data$Multiplier, c("?"="2"))
> data$Multiplier <-  revalue(data$Multiplier, c("K"="3"))
> data$Multiplier <-  revalue(data$Multiplier, c("k"="3"))
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems pretty straight forward to me. I'm pretty new too but in general I'm not sure if you can get better than one command. Though you could have combined all that:

```
> newValueVector <- c("+"="5", "?"="2", "K"="3", "k"="3")
> data$Multiplier <-  revalue(data$Multiplier, newValueVector)
```

Comment: Thanks @amustafa. Now that i think about it, yes I should have been able to figure it out. I think I was caught of guard by the `=` sign in the string.